# Calculating Big O Notation for a algorithm

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I have been asked to explaine about Big O notation and to calculate Big o Notation for an algorithm. I'm done with the  defining part but I'm still wondering how I can calculate it. Can someone help me to calculate the Big O for the below given code?

```
new = int (input("enter number" ))
if new <= 10000:
    comm=new*2/100
    print (comm)
else :
    comm= new*5/100
    print (comm)
```

Comment: As for your problem, there are many hits on Google when you search for "How to calculate big o", e.g. https://justin.abrah.ms/computer-science/how-to-calculate-big-o.html. Did you do research on big o calculation? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: yes i did  im kind of like confused on  how all these calculation stuff works

Comment: @ModusTollens thankyou for the link u sent me it somewhat cleared my doubts but it would be a great help if you can give me some instructions also

Comment: thanks a lot man thanks a lot finally understood thanks for sending me that link

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no loop, it is O(1).

Comment: can you be more specific bro

Comment: What have you tried yourself, bro?

Comment: i know the different types of big o notations and what does it means but im a bit confused in calculating big o notation for an algorithm

Comment: it would be a great help if you can give me some instructions on how to calculate big O

Comment: You only have an if-conditional, which is processed in constant time, no dependency on n => O(1)

Comment: oh kk i understood  what if my code have a if condition and as well as a while condition with an array ?

Comment: Sorry, bro, this now becomes far too broad